# How to prevent Cortana from sending voice input to Microsoft AND still be able to use speech recognition

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy, cortana, speech-recognition

I want to prevent Cortana from sending voice input to Microsoft.

But I still want to use speech recognition which will use installed 'Speech Recognition' feature.

[I don't need Cortana, if Cortana and speech recognition are different.]

What changes are needed in Settings or Group Policy or Registry?

Comment: None. What you want simply is not possible.

Comment: @LPChip Reconsider that I do't need Cortana, I just want to use speech recognition in search. (other features require Cortana, I know)

Comment: Cortana is the speech recognition, part of how Cortana works, means it uploads data.  What you want isn’t possible.

Comment: @Ramhound But, Cortana and speech recognition have separate services, viz., SearchUI and SpeechRuntime. Yet, can't they work separately?

Comment: If Cortana have to use the internet to recognize spech, then why speech recognition feature is downloaded?

Comment: Speech Recognition isn’t downloaded...  They might be separate services but Cortana works similarly to Siri,Cortana wouldn’t work very well offline.  You can disable the online search results, that’s about all you can do, on 1709 or earlier.

Comment: @Ramhound Speech recognition for my language was downloaded, I found it in 'Optional features'.

Comment: You still cannot do what you want.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok. I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, currently Cortana's speech recognition only works online, and speech data is sent to the Microsoft servers. As the result, you cannot prevent Cortana from sending voice input to Microsoft and still be able to use speech recognition.

As a side note:

- some of Cortana's voice commands still work off-line:  [Cortana: What can Cortana do while offline?](https://www.quora.com/Cortana-What-can-Cortana-do-while-offline?share=1);  [Can Cortana works offline in Win10?](https://redd.it/39qfx4).
- you could use offline speech recognition programs, the most commonly used on Microsoft Windows being Dragon Professional Individual.